# ProGuard can't remove the Log.i function calls

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, release, logcat

I use Log.i a lot in my android program and I want to remove them all in release build.

What I have done are like these:

1. Add proguard-rules.pro:

```html
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

You can see `minifyEnabled` is set to `true` and I see the .apk file sized is reduced from 1.9M to 1.2M.

2. Add 'proguard-rules.pro'

I added 'proguard-rules.pro'as:

```html
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static int v(...);
        public static int i(...);
    }
-dontwarn okio.**
```

I'm sure it's used because there were many warning of okio* warnings before then the warnings are gone after I added `-dontwarn`.

To make sure the logs are gone, I run the app on a device which is connected to a PC with Android Studio running. It's not in debug mode, but I just use its Android Monitor -> logcat to see if there is any log output.

The strange thing is that I still see log output from my app. like

```
10-14 18:53:01.436 3173-3173/? I/b: send: 03 ed 00 02 55
```

Which is the result of my code of

```
Log.i(TAG, "send: "+ toHex(req));
```

From the `?` of the log, I assume ProGuard worked (otherwise it should be my full app name). But why I still see the logcat logs?
Which step have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead of `proguard-android.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the optimized proguard config which let's the proguard to optimize your code.

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```